# How do I add ArcObjects Version to a Visual Basic project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, arcobjects

I am developing a Visual Basic project in Visual Studio 2010 that uses ArcObjects. (I have ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.) I am getting the error "'RuntimeManager' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level." A previous answer, [Esri ArcObjects--Esri.ArcGIS.Version assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905189/esri-arcobjects-esri-arcgis-version-assembly/18996199#18996199?newreg=ae1822940f6d464f9ecb8328bad883d0), recommended adding a reference to Esri.ArcGIS.Version by clicking on Project, Add Reference, selecting it under .NET and clicking OK. I have tried to do this, but it's not under .NET. What can I do to make it available?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find it if you use the Browse option.
The ESRI.ArcGIS.Version.dll file should be under your DeveloperKit installation folder. For me it is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.2\DotNet
```